# AJAX callback for file download including error handling

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot

jsp

```html
<button
  type="submit"
  id="btn_load"
  value="Search"
  class="btn btn-primary"
>Generate I-618</button>
```

js

```js
$("#btn_load").click(function (e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  form = $("#bookList");
  var post_url = form.attr("action");
  let form_data = form.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqX) {
      // Create a Blob from the data
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain" });

      // Create a link element
      var link = document.createElement("a");

      // Set the download attribute and create a URL for the file
      link.download = "your_filename.txt";
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      // Append the link to the document
      document.body.appendChild(link);

      // Trigger a click on the link to initiate the download
      link.click();

      // Remove the link from the document
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      $(".alert.alert-danger").text("Alert:success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Handle errors by Displaying a message to user????
      $(".alert.alert-danger").text("Alert: Failure");
    },
  });
});
```

java

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/book.htm")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> bookselection(
        @ModelAttribute("books") Books book, Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result) {
    List<InputStreamResource> listStream = new ArrayList<InputStreamResource>();
    String fileName = "book.txt"
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(bookList)) {
        File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".txt");
        FileWriter interfaceFileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter interfaceBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(interfaceFileWriter);
        //write to file
        for (Book list : bookList) {
        interfaceBufferedWriter.write(list.getDelimitedRecord(delimiter, nullValue));
        }
        interfaceBufferedWriter.close();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName + ".txt", fileName + ".txt");

        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        if (file != null && file.exists()) {
            listStream.add(resource);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).headers(headers).body(resource);
        }
    }
    return null; //HOW TO RETURN ERROR STRING OR OBJECT??
}
```

if there is an error in Java code while writing to file, I would like return error string. Since the method returns `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`, how do I handle sending error message from java to ajax.

- How to return error message/error object from java ??
- How to read error Ajax "error:" that was returned by server??

Comment: Did you try to return instance new ResponseEntity<>("Custom message", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) ? Modifying the header http status > 400